# Eclipse XML formatting changes order of tags?

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

I just noticed something strange. If I have this XML:

```
<level number="7" background="background_5">
```

and I press `CTRL-SHIFT-F (Format)` the code suddenly changes to this:

```
<level background="background_5" number="7" >
```

I can hardly imagine that the changing of the file is done on purpose, since I got some serious problems while parsing the files, since I access the attributes by index.

Is there a reason, except that it's being ordered by alphabet, that it's being formatted like this, and more importantly, how do I turn it off?

Comment: Which editor are you using that's doing that?

Comment: Please, tell me how to turn that feature ON!  I have a vendor that randomly reorders attributes in config files and it is playing hell with version control and knowing what actually changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) explicitly says that the order of attributes is not guaranteed:

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

You might find a way to change the behavior of the XML formatter in Eclipse, but the most robust solution is to access attributes by name instead of index. Otherwise your code will remain sensitive to changes that are perfectly legal according to the XML spec.

See also:

- [Order of XML attributes after DOM processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726395/order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing)
- [Can I enforce the order of XML attributes using a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682131/can-i-enforce-the-order-of-xml-attributes-using-a-schema)

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to disable it. I tried accessing it by name before, but somehow that didn't work correctly for me, so I did it like this. I will just not use format then. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Eli Acherkan's answer regarding not relying on order of attributes when processing XML documents.

Having said that, one could have stylistic reasons for having attributes in a particular order. In some cases, it can also make the XML document easier to read to group related attributes.

Looking at Eclipse XML formatting preferences, I don't see anything related to attribute order.

[image: Eclipse XML Formatting Preferences]

From your example, it looks like the behavior might be to sort attributes alphabetically, but I haven't performed tests to confirm that theory. Another thing it could be doing is sorting attributes in order that they appear in the XSD/DTD. You may want to test this theory as that could give you some control over the order.

You may also want to [open an enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing) for a preference to control this formatter behavior.