# Internet Explorer displaying XML attributes in random order

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

i am opening an `xml` file in Internet Explorer (9, Windows 7 64-bit).

Internet Explorer likes to display element attributes in *random order*, e.g.:

[image]

rather than in declared order:

```
<ApplicationVersion major="2" minor="2" release="12" build="687">2.2.12.687</ApplicationVersion>
```

e.g.:

[image]

Or

[image]

rather than:

[image]

Is there an element, attribute, xml-dtd, xml-schema, Internet Explorer option, Windows option anywhere that will instruct IE to display the XML in declared, rather than random order?

Comment: Internet Explorer appears to be ordering them in reverse when serializing the attributes. Chrome and Firefox do not exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Seems like this has been blogged about here: http://cggallant.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/domparsers-parsefromstring-function-and.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are unordered as defined by the xml standard.

from the standard:

```
Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

If you require order in attributes you are going to have to change your markup. I suggest something like the following:

```
<ApplicationVersion>
  <attribute name="major">2</attribute>
  <attribute name="minor">2</attribute>
  <attribute name="build">687</attribute>
</ApplicationVersion>
```

links:
[Order of XML attributes after DOM processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726395/order-of-xml-attributes-after-dom-processing)
[Can I enforce the order of XML attributes using a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682131/can-i-enforce-the-order-of-xml-attributes-using-a-schema)

Comment: Compare the IE screenshot with the copy-paste of the source code, and the screenshot of the source code.

Comment: Accepted for **not possible**.

Comment: Weird stuff when you observe it for the first time... thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11 also has this disappointing failure to xml display as written.

Use Chrome instead to display xml, it also has colour syntax highlighting.