# I want to user defined sequence while writting XML using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using DOM parser to read & write XML but the major issue I am facing is the predefined sequence of writting attributes inside the seAttribute() methods.
as for example:

```
<field calendar="" essential="false" iskeyfield="" label="label.dtPk3" maxlength="10" name="dtPk3" readonly="true" size="20"  sorter="string" sortlist="3" styleClass="text" type="text" />
```

I am writing in the sequence shown below:

```
 elemement_field.setAttribute("name", field.getName());
 elemement_field.setAttribute("type", field.getType());
 elemement_field.setAttribute("label",field.getField_label());
 elemement_field.setAttribute("size", field.getSize());
```

so please tell me a way which writes in the sequence defined by me instead of writting in sorted manner.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682131/can-i-enforce-the-order-of-xml-attributes-using-a-schema

Comment: According to this link we can't enforce a sequence.

Comment: why does the sequence matter?

Comment: @ sharonbn :Actually client needs the sequence